# JSF 2.1 (faces-config.xml)

Tags: eclipse, jsf, jsf-2

I created a Dynamic web project in eclipse(JUNO) with JSF2.1  features , i followed all the steps in below link, http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jst.jsf.doc.user%2Fhtml%2Fgettingstarted%2Ftutorial%2FJSFTools_tutorial_JSF20.html

My problem is faces-config file is in XML format only but i didn't get the "Introduction ,Overview,Navigation rule,Managed-bean ,component,others and source "  tabs . in faces.config.xml file ..

how can i get the tabs?

Comment: XML configuration is odd. You can use annotations if xml usage is not a requirement.

Comment: It maybe because your faces-config.xml got corrupted. What you can do is redo all the steps. I have faced the similar situation before, where faces-config.xml was only showing the source tab.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to open it with the Faces Config Editor. To do that,

1. Right-click your faces-config.xml >> Open With >> Other
2. Within **Internal Editors**, select `Faces Config Editor`

To make it permanent,

1. Go to General >> Editors >> File Associations
2. In the **File Types** section, click Add >> `faces-config.xml`
3. Click on the now listed faces-config.xml in this section
4. In the **Associated Editors** section, click `Faces Config Editor` >> Default

Comment: thanks for your kind information , followed the above steps in my eclipse (Juno) editor .its working good . Thanks Vrushank